WordPress Content Blocked in Editor View - Docker + NGINX Setup
I’m setting up a WordPress site with Docker and NGINX, but I’m running into an issue where the content within the WordPress editor is blocked, displaying a message, “This content is blocked. Contact the site owner to fix the issue.”
Setup Details:
1.  WordPress and MySQL are running in Docker containers.
2.  NGINX is used as a web server, with configurations to support SSL via Certbot.

Configuration Summary:
•   Docker Compose file includes MySQL, WordPress, and NGINX services.
•   NGINX config specifies SSL certificates and FastCGI handling for PHP requests.

I’ve attached relevant parts of my docker-compose.yml and NGINX configuration below:
# Docker Compose
version : '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: wordpress_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
    volumes:
      - rn_dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    networks:
      - rn-network

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.wordpress
      args:
        WC_GZD_ENCRYPTION_KEY: ${WC_GZD_ENCRYPTION_KEY}
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
    volumes:
      - rn_wordpress:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - rn-network

  webserver:
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    image: nginx:1.27.2-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - rn_wordpress:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - rn-network
...

NGINX Configuration:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name retronexus.io www.retronexus.io;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name retronexus.io www.retronexus.io;
    client_max_body_size 64M;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/html;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/retronexus.io/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/retronexus.io/privkey.pem;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:
•   Verified SSL certificate setup is correct.
•   Checked NGINX logs, but no specific errors related to blocked content in the WordPress editor.
•   Confirmed permissions on /var/www/html are set to allow access from both the NGINX and WordPress containers.

Could there be any misconfigurations in the NGINX setup that might block content within the WordPress editor? Or is there a specific setting required to avoid content blocking? Any advice on debugging this issue or additional settings that could be relevant would be appreciated.
